The order of the element $\sigma$ of the symmetric group $S_5$ is
The order of the element $\sigma = \begin{pmatrix}
1 &2  &3  &4  &5 \\ 
\downarrow &\downarrow  &\downarrow &\downarrow  &\downarrow \\ 
4 &5  &1  &3  &2 
\end{pmatrix}$ of the symmetric group $S_5$ is
$\text{(A)}\space 2$ $\space\space\space\space\space\space\space\space\space\space$ $\text{(B)}\space 3$ $\space\space\space\space\space\space\space\space\space\space$ $\text{(C)}\space 6$ $\space\space\space\space\space\space\space\space\space\space$ $\text{(D)}\space 8$ $\space\space\space\space\space\space\space\space\space\space$ $\text{(E)}\space 12$

My ATTEMPT: Regardless of the notation I use:
$$\sigma = \begin{pmatrix}
1 &2  &3  &4  &5 \\ 
\downarrow &\downarrow  &\downarrow &\downarrow  &\downarrow \\ 
4 &5  &1  &3  &2 \\
\downarrow &\downarrow  &\downarrow &\downarrow  &\downarrow \\ 
3 &2  &4  &1  &5 \\
\downarrow &\downarrow  &\downarrow &\downarrow  &\downarrow \\ 
1 &5  &3  &4  &2 \\
\downarrow &\downarrow  &\downarrow &\downarrow  &\downarrow \\ 
4 &2  &1  &3  &5 \\
\downarrow &\downarrow  &\downarrow &\downarrow  &\downarrow \\ 
3 &5  &4  &1  &2 \\
\downarrow &\downarrow  &\downarrow &\downarrow  &\downarrow \\ 
1 &2  &3  &4  &5 \\
\end{pmatrix}$$
So we required $6$ steps to reach to the identity $\begin{pmatrix}
1 &2  &3  &4  &5 
\end{pmatrix}$.
Hence $\text{(C)}$ is the correct option.

In fact, the given answer is also $\text{(C)}$. However:
$(1)$ Is it allowed to use that notation? I never saw it before, but I saw something like
$\begin{pmatrix}
a &b  &c\\
\end{pmatrix}\begin{pmatrix}
d &e\\
\end{pmatrix}\begin{pmatrix}
f &g\\
\end{pmatrix}$, but I do not know how to convert it to be as such.
$(2)$ Getting $\text{(C)}$ does not mean my approach is right, I am not sure. Is it right?
$(3)$ Is there a quicker way to find the order?

I approached it slightly differently but agree with your solution. I noticed that some elements require 3 steps to get back to their original state and some elements require 2 steps. Since LCM(2,3)=6 I concluded 6 steps were required to get every element back to its original state.

$(1)$ The notation $(abc)(de)(fg)$ groups together the elements of a cycle. Hence in this notation, $\sigma = \begin{pmatrix}
1 &2  &3  &4  &5 \\ 
\downarrow &\downarrow  &\downarrow &\downarrow  &\downarrow \\ 
4 &5  &1  &3  &2 
\end{pmatrix}$ would be $(1\space\space\space4\space\space\space3)(2\space\space\space5)$ (which actually means$(1\rightarrow4\rightarrow3\rightarrow1)(2\rightarrow 5\rightarrow 2)$).
$(2)$ The approach is correct.
$(3)$ Another approach might be to use the cycle notation. Since $\sigma=(1\space\space\space4\space\space\space3)(2\space\space\space5)$, and the two cycles are of order $3$ and $2$ respectively, the order of $\sigma$ would be $2\times 3=6$.

Generally the order of a permutation that is a product of disjoint cycles is the least common multiple of the lengths of the cycles

Thank you for your answer!

That is a notation which is indeed not used so first I will explain that notation to you.
Let $1\leq a_1,\dots,a_k\le n$. Define $(a_1\ a_2\ \cdots\ a_k)\in\mathrm S_n$ to be the permutation that sends $a_1$ to $a_2$, $a_2$ to $a_3$, and so on sending $a_{k-1}$ to $a_k$. Finally, it sends $a_k$ to $a_1$. Everything which is not included in the $a_i$s goes to itself. As an example, the permutation $(1\ 2\ 6\ 4)$ in $\mathrm S_6$ is the permutation
$$\begin{pmatrix}
1 &2  &3  &4  &5 &6\\ 
\downarrow &\downarrow  &\downarrow &\downarrow  &\downarrow &\downarrow\\ 
2 &6 &3  &1&5 &4
\end{pmatrix}$$
Now, for any $\sigma\in\mathrm S_n$, do the following.

Look at the list $1$, $\sigma(1)$, $\sigma^2(1)$, $\dots$. This has to start repeating at some point, suppose $\sigma^k(1)=1$. Then, let $\sigma_1=(1\ \sigma(1)\ \sigma^2(1)\ \cdots\ \sigma^k(1))$.
If $k=n$, then $\sigma=\sigma_1$ (why?). Otherwise, there is at least one element which is not among the $\sigma^i(1)$s. Let that be $b$. Then, make the list $b$, $\sigma(b)$, $\sigma^2(b)$, $\dots$. Say it repeats at $\ell$, i.e., $\sigma^\ell(b)=b$. Then, consider $\sigma_2=(b\ \sigma(b)\ \sigma^2(b)\ \cdots\ \sigma^\ell(b))$. (Check that none of these can be same as what we had got before.)
If $k+\ell=n$, then $\sigma=\sigma_1\circ\sigma_2$ (why?). Else repeat.

This will terminate and you will get $\sigma=\sigma_1\circ\sigma_2\circ\cdots\circ\sigma_r$ (why?).
As an example, take the $\sigma$ in question. The first list is $1$, $4$, $3$, $1$, $\dots$ so $\sigma_1=(1\ 4\ 3)$. Then, $b=2$ and $\sigma_2=(2\ 5)$. Check that $\sigma$ is the same permutation as the composition of $(1\ 4\ 3)$ and $(2\ 5)$. You can omit the $\circ$s and simply write
$$\sigma=(1\ 4\ 3)(2\ 5)$$

For the order of a permutation, your method is correct since you found that $\sigma^6=1$ but $\sigma^k\neq1$ for $1\leq k\le 5$.
Here is a sequence of exercises to help you find an order of a permutation from its cycle decomposition (the one we derived before).

Show that order of $(a_1\ a_2\ \cdots\ a_k)$ is $k$.
Show that if $\sigma=\sigma_1\sigma_2\dots\sigma_r$ is the cycle decomposition, then $$\sigma^2=\sigma_1^2\sigma_2^2\dots\sigma_r^2$$
Generalise 2 and use it to derive a formula for the order of $\sigma$ in terms of lengths of the cycles.

Hope this helps. :)

Thank you for this detailed explanation!
